# Sort two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How to sort a two-dimensional array in the following example

```
var films = [
   ["action,sci-fi",             "Star Wars",               "description..."],
   ["comedy,adventure,sci-fi",   "Back to the future",      "description..."],
   ["drama",                     "The Green Mile",          "description..."],
   ["drama,comedy",              "Forrest Gump",            "description..."],
   ["fantasy,adventure",         "The Lord of the Rings",   "description..."],
];
```

sort to:

```
var films = [
   ["comedy,adventure,sci-fi",   "Back to the future",      "description..."],
   ["drama,comedy",              "Forrest Gump",            "description..."],
   ["action,sci-fi",             "Star Wars",               "description..."],
   ["drama",                     "The Green Mile",          "description..."],
   ["fantasy,adventure",         "The Lord of the Rings",   "description..."],
];
```

Comment: What is sorted in provided example ?

Comment: FWIW, those films starting with "The" should be formatted "Green Mile, The" etc imo. Makes for easier searching if there's a long list. There are a lot of films that start with "The" :)

Comment: why have arrays in an array when you can have objects in an array with a key value pair?

Comment: I can think of a number of films that share the same name (most remakes) that wouldn't suit that structure.

Comment: @Andy OP is doing exactly the same thing now. I don't see the difference.     Movies with the same name are listed the same as with objects.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking you meant that you would use the film names as the keys and then have the values as an object containing the other values. My mistake. You mean an array of objects, right?

Comment: @Andy, yes that is what I mean. I think that is way more readable. I will post it as an answer here

Answer (score 3):

If you're sorting by the string in the index position of 1 then:

```
films.sort(function(item1, item2){
  if (item1[1] > item2[1]) 
    return 1;
  if (item1[1] < item2[1]) 
    return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: I would remove `else`. Just have the two conditions and return 0 if neither of them are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the structure of your array and make objects instead of arrays. A simplified version of what I mean using pure javascript.

```
var films = [
 {name: "Star Wars"},
 {name: "Back to the Future"},
 {name: "Crimsons Peak"}
]; // original array

var sortByName = []; // new array to sort by

for(i=0; i<films.length; i++) {
    sortByName.push(films[i].name);
}

console.log(sortByName); // unordered

console.log(sortByName.sort()); // ordered
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kwq58c0k/